# Deleted CSS file still available in joomla 3.2.3

Tags: php, css, caching, joomla

I'm using joomla 3.2.3. I have deleted css folder in my template.

This is not found.
http://www.gleeon.com/templates/youtheme/css

But this is exists.
http://www.gleeon.com/templates/youtheme/css/template.min.css

How it is possible?

I have cleared my browser cache and cleared cache in joomla backend. And this css file is available in all systems, not only my system. Do i need to do anything in cPanel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get a "404 Not Found" page for both links.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the issue.

When i ping both gleeon.com and www.gleeon.com it shows different IP address:

```
104.28.5.123 for www.gleeon.com (with www)
69.160.44.137 for gleeon.com (without www)
```

So when you try to hit below URL it will give you not found

```
http://gleeon.com/templates/youtheme/css/template.min.css
```

But when you try to hit below URL it will show you the file code as it is different IP address:

```
http://www.gleeon.com/templates/youtheme/css/template.min.css
```

So the www.gleeon.com is being pointed to other server.

Please ask with your hosting guys to check it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are still seeing the file is because it is being cached somewhere. There are a lot of places it could be cached between the server and client side. Make sure all server side document caching is cleared, and make sure you clear your browsing data.

I have visited both links, and I can confirm that template.min.css does not exist.

You can find where it is cached by trying to open the file in a different browser. If the file is not found in a different browser, then the caching is happening in the browser.

Also always Control+Shift+R (or command+shift+r on mac) to refresh to make sure the site is fully reloaded. Some browsers like chrome also have a developer mode and allow you to disable caching while you are developing.
You can do this by entering the Developer Tools (alt+command+I on mac), then clicking on the settings icon in the right upper corner and selecting the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option.

Good luck.